# AJAX post method working in one area but not another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX post method that works in two places both on "Ladder" page, but not another, a "matches" page. This method sets posts the "player ID" which php picks up and sets a session variable

```
$("form .singles-player-name").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var viewPlayer = $(this).val();
    console.log(viewPlayer);

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            viewPlayerID: viewPlayer
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
        //console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "Player";
    });
});
```

Working page form:

```
<form><button type='submit' id='playerInfo' class='singles-player-name' name='viewPlayer' value='",$sglsPlayerID,"'>", $curSGLSRankLName, ", ", $curSGLSRankFName, "</button></form>
```

Sets session variable

```
if (!empty($_POST['viewPlayerID'])){
$viewPlayer = isset($_POST['viewPlayerID']) ? $_POST['viewPlayerID'] : 'No data found';

$viewPlayerSql = "SELECT * FROM `PLAYERS` WHERE `ID` LIKE '".$viewPlayer."'";
$viewPlayerQuery = @$conn->query($viewPlayerSql);
$viewPlayerRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewPlayerQuery);

$_SESSION['playerID'] = $viewPlayerRow["ID"];
echo "", $_SESSION['playerID'],"";}
```

Second working version that lives on the same page as the first but is for doubles players:

```
$("form .doubles-player-name").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var viewPlayer = $(this).val();
    console.log(viewPlayer);

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            viewPlayerID: viewPlayer
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
        //console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "Player";
    });
});
```

Form for that ajax method:

```
<form><button type='submit' id='playerInfo' class='doubles-player-name' name='viewPlayer' value='",$dblsPlayerID,"'>", $curDBLSRankLName, ", ", $curDBLSRankFName, "</button></form>
```

Then on complete, the ajax methods redirect to the player page and pulls up that players info on that page (ex. https://urlexample.com/Player). This part, from this point-up, works! However, I have another page, the "Matches" page, where I want it to do the same exact thing, and set that session variable, then redirect to the player page, so I have this method below. But for some reason, this one does *not* work:

```
$("form .singlesMatch-player1-name").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var viewPlayer = $(this).val();
    console.log(viewPlayer);

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            viewPlayerID: viewPlayer
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "Player";
    });
});
```

Not working form:

```
<form><button type='submit' id='playerInfo' class='singlesMatch-player1-name' name='viewPlayer' value='",$sglsPlayer1ID,"'>", $P1LN, ", ", $P1FN, "</button></form>
```

For some reason, all this second method does is post it to the URL (ex. https://urlexample.com/WeeklyMatchUps?viewPlayer=1) instead of setting the session variable and redirecting to the player page (ex. https://urlexample.com/Player). All thats different between the 2 is the class name of the button.

Comment: is the posting url correct for the not working example? aren't you posting all data to the same file? which is i guess `index.php` ?

Comment: @line88 it's posting to back to the page itself. See: ( $.ajax({url: ' ', ...). This is working in the first 2 examples, but not the 3rd

Comment: yeah, i saw it, it's just weird to me...try printing out `$_POST` array

Comment: @line88 I can see what its posting, but for some reason, its sending it to the url instead of actually processing. The 2 working examples do NOT append the posted data to the URL... exampleurl . com/WeeklyMatchUps?viewPlayer=2

Comment: hmm, that's odd. but try changing your buttons `type` attribute to `type='button'`, that way you will `click` on the button and not `submit` the form. it's weird that's its working on first 2 examples..because the reason you get appended data to the url is that the form is sending data using `GET` method

Comment: @line88 Okay, get this, if I change button type to 'button' on one of the 2 working examples, it still works... if i change it on the 3rd, it prevents it from submitting the form, but now also does not post the data at all, not to URL like it was before, or anything.

Comment: hmm..oh try moving evt.preventDefault to the bottom of the click function on not working example.this is really weird, can you check your `doctype` at the each page, are they the same?

Comment: both pages are <!DOCTYPE html>... no dice on moving the preventdefault to the bottom of the click function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182817/discussion-between-line88-and-slabach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a function being called on the page that was commented out causing an error before jQuery was added in a script at the bottom of the page. removing that function from being called fixed the issue.

S/O to @line88 for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

$sglsPlayer1ID should probably be $sglsPlayerID.

Also, try adding a success and error condition to your AJAX conditions instead of just using a done operator.  This will allow you to dump helpful error codes on a failure to better resolve these kinds of issues in the future.

Comment: The issue isn't the value being set in button, that is getting the correct value. Also, I cannot get an error function working in the non-working ajax method. the evt.preventdefault is also seemingly not working and on click, it is refreshing the page, so I cannot view any console messages that might have been logged

Comment: If you remark window.location.href = "Player"; you should be able to prevent the refresh to see your console messages.  Also, check if $sglsPlayer1ID is a sanitized string.  If it contains certain special characters such as from someone named O'Conner, it might be breaking at console.log(viewPlayer);  causing subsequent scripts to fail as well.

Comment: the value it's getting is literally just "1" or "2" etc. Also, commenting out the window.location line, still refreshes the page due to the preventdefault not functioning properly